# Regex: skip comments within quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

With this regex **`/#(.*?)\r?\n|#(.*?)$/g`** am able to parse the content below but it also matches the comment within the quotes.

How do I avoid this?

```
#
# this is a comment
#

but this is '# not a comment'
and this is "# not a comment either"

# help, please
```

I tried **`/(?!\B["'][^']*)(#(.*?)\r?\n|#(.*?)$)(?![^']*['"]\B)/g`**
 but the results are buggy.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple code to match a comment only at the beginning of a line

```
/^#(.*?)$/gm
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YngpW9/1/

Alternative code to match the comment anywhere

```
/^[^'"]*?(#.*?)$/gm
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YngpW9/2/

Make sure to use `gm` , not just `g`, so that you can make use of `^` which matches the beginning of a line.

This is an example

```js
var string = `
#
# this is a comment
#

but this is '# not a comment'
and this is "# not a comment either"

# help, please
`;
var regex = /^[^'"]*?(#.*?)$/gm;
var match = regex.exec(string);
while (match != null) {
  document.write(match[1]+'<br>')
  match = regex.exec(string);
}
```

Comment: Might be nice to explain that `^` matches beginning of line, it doesn't really skip things in quotes per se.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my answer to explain `^`. It is true that `^#` doesn't skip things in quotes per se, but I think it will do the job if the comments occur at the beginning of a line which is typically the case.

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim. Seems to work well. Though not part of the question. What would match the block comments - /* blah blah */ but not the ones within the quotes.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar It is my pleasure. Glad I can help.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar As for `/* blah */` case, I would do it with this regex `^\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/$` , demo: https://regex101.com/r/hIT8rj/1/

Comment: @Ibrahim, must really appreciate your efforts in putting up a demo as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @nnnnnn I added additional regex to fix the issue that you brought up. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use capture groups and alternation to distinguish between the contexts you want, and the contexts you don't want. This is a technique I learned from [this article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

The trick is to only put the thing you want to match in a capture group, and leave all other alternatives out of the capture group. Then you will filter your result matches based on whether or not they have a capture group.

The regex would look like this:

```
/'(?:\\.|.)*?'|"(?:\\.|.)*?"|#(.*)$/gm
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8B5br/2)

You would use it like this:

```js
var re = /'(?:\\.|.)*?'|"(?:\\.|.)*?"|#(.*)$/gm;
var str = `
#
# this is a comment
#

but this is '# not a comment'
and this is "# not a comment either"

# help, please
`;

str.replace(re, function(match, group1) {
  if (group1 !== undefined) {
    console.log(match);
  }
});
```

You can even [extend this to match multi-line comments](https://regex101.com/r/y5FCV7/3).

```js
var re = /'(?:\\.|.)*?'|"(?:\\.|.)*?"|(#(.*)$|\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/)/gm;
var str = `
#
# this is a comment
#

/*
this is a
multiline comment
*/

but this is '# not a comment'
and this is "# not /* a comment */ either"

# help, please
`;

str.replace(re, function(match, group1) {
  if (group1 !== undefined) {
    console.log(match);
  }
});
```